# How to place Ads in Wowza

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

Is it possible to insert short advertising clips inbetween a single VOD file using Wowza?

You always see it on the web, but I wonder if it is rendered directly into the video or if it has some sort of application that does that (and i am not talking about a video file ***in front of*** the actual video stream).

Has anybody experience with that?

Comment: It's not rendered over video. Maybe you should check flow player and jw player 3rd party paid plugins which might support this. However, you will still need server side code for wowza to make sure that this protection is not bypassed nor hotlinked. You might need encryption as well. Basically, doing it properly IS NOT EASY. So yes, it's possible, but not for lazy people :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, please look at this article

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145

Answer (score 0):

Well of course you can, but it's not straight forward. You need to properly encode video so the seeking is working well, preferably with 1s keyframe.
Then you need to make a player with playlist support, and this playlist must have markin and markout support, so the playlist looks like this:

1. Play Advert 1
2. Play movie 0s-100s
3. Play Advert 2
4. Play movie 100s - 200s

Also, the player must know that you are playing advert (so it wont allow you to skip during this time), it needs to support linear seeking of the playlist (so you can seek whole video even if it's made out of playlist) etc - there are no free players doing all of that, I am sorry.